# Login(authenticate) using Token python

Tags: cookies, connection, token, login-script

I need to get the header cookie and the token identification for connection on a website

im a new on python

```
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_users" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="user.login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="aHR0cDovL2FuaW1lZGlnaXRhbG5ldHdvcmsuZnIv" />
    <input type="hidden" name="5fec53862a690d567fdcb932a2b68728" value="1" />   </fieldset>
```

ty

Comment: What have you tried? What is getting you trouble? Have you tried googling how to get cookie and form parameter values in python?

Comment: yes I have searched but found nothing im a noobz